# manage.pyのコマンドの詳細なヘルプが見たい

Tags: django

djangoのmanage.py help　でコマンドを確認できますが、そのコマンドの詳細な使い方を見れるコマンドはありますか？

https://hodalog.com/how-to-revert-migrations/
リンク先のmigrateの使い方などをhelpなどを使ってオプションを確認できますか？

たとえば、manage.py　でmigrateコマンドでマイグレイションを以前を戻したり、zeroを使ってリセットしたりできるとおもいますが、helpなどのコマンドから確認できるかということです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コマンドよりも、このページで解説されている内容と思われます。
helpコマンドも冒頭に記述されていますが、コマンド記述とオプションのリスト程度らしいので、結局このページの内容になるのでは？

[django-admin と manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.0/ref/django-admin/)

> 本項ではコマンドラインの実行例は一貫して **django-admin** を使用しますが、実行例は全て **manage.py** もしくは **python -m django** でも同様に利用可能です。

ただし、日本語化は少なめで多くが英語のままなので、英語のページを機械翻訳に掛けた方が良いかもしれません。
いきなりhelpの呼び出し方自身が以下のように英語のままです。

> **Getting runtime help**
>
> django-admin help
>
> Run **django-admin help** to display usage information and a list of the commands provided by each application.
> Run **django-admin help --commands** to display a list of all available commands.
> Run **django-admin help <command>** to display a description of the given command and a list of its available options.

上記の英語ページ
[django-admin and manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/)
[migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#migrate)
[showmigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり英語力を磨かないとどこがかんじんな場所かわからないですね。機械翻訳を駆使していこうとおもいます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`manage.py help 〈知りたいコマンド〉` で表示されます。

最初に `manage.py help` した際にこのように出力されている通りです。

> Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Comment: よくみてませんでした（焦　ありがとうございます